# How can I intercept hyperlink click from datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, hyperlink, crm

Right now I have a datagrid with a template column as follows:

`<asp:TemplateColumn> <ItemTemplate> <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Target="_blank" /> </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateColumn>`

The OnItemDataBound method builds the NavigateURL property of the Hyperlink dynamically, based on another column in this datagrid, which contains a GUID. Selecting a row by clicking on the hyperlink brings up a Dynamics CRM web page for the Contact with that GUID. This program is launched from a ribbon button click in CRM, via a JScript.

This system works fine but I find I now need to intercept that click event. I tried adding a OnSelectedIndexChanged event but this was ignored; execution did not seem to stop there.

Is there any way to intercept the hyperlink click, or, conversely, is there another control I can use that will allow building dynamic URLs and also interception of a click event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this on client, specifically in "onclick" event.

Create a JavaScript function, e.g. `clickIntercept()` that would perform nessessery operations befor navigation; then in the code where you assign NavigateURL property assign "onclick" attribute with the value of "clickIntercept".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, Trekstuff.

I also found that I could change my hyperlink to a ButtonColumn, remove the OnItemDataBound code and use an OnItemCommand method instead.

For the OnItemCommand I have:

```
switch (((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).CommandName)
     {
            case "Select":    
               String selectedContact = ServerURL + QueryStringPrefix + e.Item.Cells[1].Text + QueryStringSuffix;
               Response.Redirect(selectedContact); 
               break;
     }
```

This works for me.